# order of the time series model

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, estimation

I am kind of new to time series modeling.
I am trying to fit a model for a time series variable. I am trying to fit a ARMA model.
I am using R to do the analysis. When i estimate the model using  both yule-walker method and maximum likelihood method, the output says that i need to estimate 10 coefficients.

It seems strange for me to estimate 10 coefficients. my question is , is this a possible situation or is this due to something wrong in my method?

This is the link for access the data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WfaDUB2NnhIUsRggm9eITq7D-L55u0IP

this is my code so far,

```
aus_indata <- read.csv("aus_data.csv", sep="")
tsd=ts(aus_indata$bank,frequency = 12,start=c(1981,1),end=c(1994,8))

 diffddata=diff(tsd,differences = 1)
ar.yw(x=diffdata,order.max = 10)

Call:
ar.yw.default(x = diffdata, order.max = 20)
ar.mle(x=diffdata)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10  
 0.1354  -0.1403   0.0691   0.0740  -0.1593   0.0250   0.1714  -0.1078   0.2052  -0.1471  



Call:
ar.mle(x = diffdata)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10  
 0.1390  -0.1411   0.0686   0.0784  -0.1635   0.0304   0.1714  -0.1060   0.2039  -0.1413
```

Comment: Are you being asked to estimate 10 variables or it testing what lag to add to the model to eliminate auto correlation (I am not familiar with R results)?

Comment: @user54285 my aim is to estimate a model for this data. So to estimate the time series i used yule-walked method and maximum likelihood method. So based on that output it says that i need to estimate 10 coefficients.

Comment: As I noted before I don't know R output so its difficult for me to comment on that. Nothing I know or have read about Yule Walker (aka GLS) suggest it requires you to estimate any parameters. Regression is not mechanistic that way - so that you are forced to estimate certain coefficients you are not interested in. You may have to specify the right lag to eliminate autocorrelation (which will only influence your test statistic not your slopes in any case). Incidentally, if all you care about is forecasting you would probably be better off using ARIMA than Yule Walker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get those results for two reasons. First, using the commands ar.yw and ar.mle you fit autoregressive models to your series. You can get a more parsimonious approximation, if you attempt to estimate a full ARIMA. .

See below that output auto.arima (package "forecast"). An ARIMA(2,1,2) seem to be a more suitable model for your data

```
    Series: aus_data 
ARIMA(2,1,2) 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2
      -1.2351  -0.8070  1.4221  0.9722
s.e.   0.0727   0.0701  0.0447  0.0531

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3741:  log likelihood=-150.14
AIC=310.29   AICc=310.67   BIC=325.76
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to time series and help from you is highly appreciate. So is it possible to explain the following questions which arises based on your answer ? 


1) When estimate a time series model when should i use ar.yw or ar.mle and when to use auto.arima ? because i thought when estimating ARMA model, i should always starts from ar.yw and ar.mle .

Comment: 2) Also as i figured out you obtained the result that you mentioned by fitting the time series variable as  `ts(aus_data$bank)` but when i declare the time series variable like `ts(aus_data$bank,frequency = 12,start=c(1981,1),end=c(1994,8))` (for me , it is the correct way to declare the time series as these are monthly data) i am not getting ARIMA(2,1,2). What may be the reason behind that ?

Comment: See R Help files:
ar{stas}: Fit an AUTOREGRESSIVE time series model to the data, by default selecting the complexity by AIC.

It does not fit arima

Comment: Please note, you can also use command arima (package stats). eg arima(x = aus_ts, order = c(2, 1, 2)) to fit ARIMA model. Also note, it is indeed good practice to define time series as ts objects but estimation results will not change in most cases (existence of seasonality is one of those exceptions). Run arima() command on aus_ts <- ts(aus_data, frequency=12, start=c(1981,1),end=c(1994,8)) and you'll get identical estimation results (but note: auto.arima will suggest for some reason a random walk ).